# procedimiento almacenado .netcore web api

Tags: c#, stored-procedure, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, ado.net

Hola  estoy construyendo una web api en asp .netcore, estoy utilizando procedimientos almacenados para poder manejar consultas mas complejas, cosa que con etity framework para mi es mas complicado, estoy utilizando ado.net para realizar dicha conexión.
He conseguido hacer la conexión a un procedimiento almacenado y utilizar los métodos get y post, la cuestión es que no se como hacer para  poder llamar los demás procedimientos almacenados y mapear una ruta para interactuar via get o post en el mismo proyecto. Solo he podido con uno, y pues no creo que sea lo mas conveniente crearme una web api por cada función que cumpla un procedimiento **almacenado**.

mi proyecto lo compone tres carpetas que se llaman **controller,** **Data,** **Modelos**
dentro de modelos esta la clase value 
que tiene el siguiente código

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ASPNETCore_StoredProcs.Models
{
    public class Value
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Value1 { get; set; }
        public string Value2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

carpeta data tiene una clase que se llama Valuerepository

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ASPNETCore_StoredProcs.Data
{
    public class ValuesRepository
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString;

        public ValuesRepository(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("defaultConnection");
        }

        public async Task<List<Value>> GetAll()
        {
            using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetAllValues", sql))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    var response = new List<Value>();
                    await sql.OpenAsync();

                    using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                    {
                        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                        {
                            response.Add(MapToValue(reader));
                        }
                    }

                    return response;
                }
            }
        }

        private Value MapToValue(SqlDataReader reader)
        {
            return new Value()
            {
                Id = (int)reader["Id"],
                Value1 = (int)reader["Value1"],
                Value2 = reader["Value2"].ToString()
            };
        }

        public async Task<Value> GetById(int Id)
        {
            using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetValueById", sql))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", Id));
                    Value response = null;
                    await sql.OpenAsync();

                    using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                    {
                        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                        {
                            response = MapToValue(reader);
                        }
                    }

                    return response;
                }
            }
        }

        public async Task Insert(Value value)
        {
            using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertValue", sql))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@value1", value.Value1));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@value2", value.Value2));
                    await sql.OpenAsync();
                    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        public async Task DeleteById(int Id)
        {
            using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DeleteValue", sql))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", Id));
                    await sql.OpenAsync();
                    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

y por ultimo tengo a Controller que tiene una clase que se llama valuescontroller

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ASPNETCore_StoredProcs.Data;
using ASPNETCore_StoredProcs.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace ASPNETCore_StoredProcs.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ValuesRepository _repository;

        public ValuesController(ValuesRepository repository)
        {
            this._repository = repository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(repository));
        }

        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Value>>> Get()
        {
            return await _repository.GetAll();
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Value>> Get(int id)
        {
            var response = await _repository.GetById(id);
            if (response == null) { return NotFound(); }
            return response;
        }

        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task Post([FromBody] Value value)
        {
            await _repository.Insert(value);
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task Delete(int id)
        {
           await _repository.DeleteById(id);
        }
    }
}
```

esta es mi clase startup

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ASPNETCore_StoredProcs.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace ASPNETCore_StoredProcs
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<ValuesRepository>();
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Agradezco si me pueden ayudar o si es como pienso que debo crear una api por cada procedimiento que se realice gracias

Comment: Según lo que entendí, la forma en que debieses hacerlo es crear un método por cada procedimiento que necesites, no necesariamente una WebAPI; a menos que desees consultar N procedimientos en un método para poder retornar toda la info. Si puedes aclarar mejor la pregunta, sería genial!

Comment: es que creo los métodos pero no se como hacer el direccionamiento http get para poder indicarle cual ruta que  debe dirigirse

Comment: Y que te impide hacerlo mediante Route? Ya lo estás haciendo por lo que vi

Comment: la verdad no se como empezar o como hacerlo

Comment: `[Route("rutaProcedimiento1")]` y asi, hasta lo que necesites

Comment: Paulo Urbano Rivera me sirvio su orientacion